# How can I solve problems installing packages in python (Failed building wheels)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, google-colaboratory, scikit-image

I'm trying to install several packages in Google Colab (python 3.7) and I find some errors.

The packages I'm installing are:

1. pillow==4.2.1
2. numpy==1.16.1
3. pandas==0.20.3
4. scipy==0.19.1
5. scikit-image==0.13.0
6. scikit-learn==0.19.1
7. matplotlib==2.2.2
8. tensorflow==1.2.1
9. concurrent-iterator==0.2.6

At first, I do:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Then, I do the next (it is an example of one package):

```
!pip install pillow==4.2.1
```

But whit packages 4, 5 and 6 I found the next error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -andas (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -andas (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting scipy==0.19.1
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz (14.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for scipy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -andas (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages)
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -andas (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages)
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.4.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for scipy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
  WARNING: No metadata found in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
  Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy-1.4.1.dist-info/
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/~cipy-1.4.1.dist-info
  Moving to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/
   from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/~cipy
    error: legacy-install-failure

    × Encountered error while trying to install package.
    ╰─> scipy

    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

After that, the version installed is the default in Google Colab, not the one I want.

I found this error only with packages 4, 5 and 6 and, after looking for information on internet, i didn't find a solution. I can't install modern versions because I need those in particular.

Comment: Having the same issue at the moment with scipy 1.0.1. Did you by any chance manage to fix it ?